# Switching letter case of a string in C

Tags: c

Basically, I had to convert all lowercase letters to uppercase but I figured I'd extend the example a bit. So my current code changes the current case to its opposite:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
  int i=0;
  char str[] = "Test String";
  char c;

  while (str[i])
  {
    if (isupper(str[i])){
        c=str[i];
        putchar(tolower(c));
        i++;
    } else if (islower(str[i])){
        c=str[i];
        putchar(toupper(c));
        i++;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Works fine when there are no space characters or delimiters. The above would output only `tEST`, while I want it to process the whole string and return `tEST sTRING`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to include the case in which the character satisfies neither condition:

```
while (str[i])
{
  if (isupper(str[i])){
      c=str[i];
      putchar(tolower(c));
      i++;
  } else if (islower(str[i])){
      c=str[i];
      putchar(toupper(c));
      i++;
  } else {
      c=str[i];
      putchar(c);
      i++;
  }
}
```

Otherwise, the program gets "stuck" on the space, never advancing `i`, not printing out anything.

---

This program can also be simplified. There's a lot of repetition as it currently stands. Here's a simpler version:

```
char str[] = "Test String";

for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
{
    putchar(isupper(str[i]) ? tolower(str[i]) : toupper(str[i]));
}
return 0;
```

Comment: So generally, the space and any other 'non-supported'/non-alpha character will be processed through the last `else` clause? Thanks for your time :) Will accept the answer ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

add

```
else
{
    c=str[i];
    putchar(c);
    i++;
}
```